# Show "Republished" badge when Post Date is manipulated

Tags: custom-post-types, front-end

I am transitioning from Drupal to Wordpress and I love the way Wordpress handles pretty much every aspect.

Although the transition is smooth I have a question. I am using WP-Types plugin to create views and custom post types.

What I want to do is to find a handle that I can use to show a "Republished" badge on a product when an admin manipulates the Post Date.

Any ideas on this one ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for determining the case, if [`get_the_date()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) and [`get_the_modified_date`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_date) differ, then the post has been modified - updated or republished.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, all I have to do is to check in my loop if these dates differ.

Comment: @KonstantinosKoletsas My pleasure, yes.

Comment: @KonstantinosKoletsas Of course that won't show a badge or anything - just to clarify.

Comment: I am aware of that I just needed the handle. Thanks again.